# Simultaneous alphanumeric key presses (jk) in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to use simultaneous alphanumeric key presses to remap keys or to call commands in Sublime Text 3?

I'd like to remap simultaneous presses of <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd> (or just to exit the `insert mode` in Vintageous). I saw how to do it using modifiers (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>) and sequential commands (first <kbd>j</kbd> and after <kbd>k</kbd>), but not concurrently.

Comment: as far as I know this isn't possible without using some Python library to monitor keypresses

Comment: It's a pity... But thank you, @KeithHall